# How do I make my Vue webpage fill the entire viewport?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using a demo web app built using Vue 3, Vue Router, and Bootstrap, via Vue CLI. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get my webpage to fill the full height of the browser window.

I've tried using bootstrap to set `vh-100` on the highest level div, but it still seems to vertically match the content's minimum height instead of consuming the entire visible viewport height.

How can I make my app's layout obey Bootstrap's `vh-100` attribute?

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App"
}
</script>
```

LoginPage.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="vh-100 container" id="app">
    <div class="row vh-25">
      <div class="image-container row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img src="../assets/images/pic.png" alt="picture">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vh-75">
      <EmailForm/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EmailForm from '@/components/EmailForm.vue'; // @ is an alias to /src

export default {
  components: {
    EmailForm,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(~@/assets/images/background_pic.jpg) repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap version 4.1 or greater?

Comment: Yep, I'm using bootstrap 4.5.3

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do that. In Vue typically `#app` is the highest level so you could set a min-height there.

```
#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Or you could set the `.container` element to be a fixed position and cover the viewport.

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nice, this seems to work, however when I use the first solution (#app) there's a margin around my entire background and the page is slightly scrollable. What's causing this?

Comment: Hard to say what's causing spacing issues without being able to see the whole thing but you might want to set `margin: 0; padding:0` on both the body and the `#app` element.

Comment: `margin: 0 and padding: 0` didn't fix the issue when set on either the `#app` or `#body` elements. What else would you need to see beyond the code in my question to identify where the margin is being added?